# ME21N order quantity violates rounding rules

Tags: excel, vba, sap-erp

I want to create mass PO automation. The problem is my PO quantity in my Excel file is `75`, `4`, `10` but in SAP ERP it rounds up to `80`, `10`, `10`.

I have tried changing the format of the Excel column to numbers, does not work either.

I need SAP ERP to not round up the quantity.

Comment: What is ME21N? What data type is `80,10,10`? It doesn't look like a number with the commas placed in these odd positions. You need to provide more information, so people who can't look inside your head will have a chance to understand what you're talking about.

Comment: @teylyn ME21N is a tcode used in SAP. The number in commas which are placed in odd positions are a series of numbers. what i meant was 75 in excel shows up as 80 in SAP, 4 in excel shows up as 10 in SAP.

Comment: We had some pretty strict rules that SAP GUI Scripting was only to be used to extract data and never to write to SAP. It came about because of these anomalies that subsequently made it really difficult to trace and correct. Is there another way you can do it like a bulk upload template? I know we had one for work scheduling and time confirmations.

Comment: I don't see the connection to Excel. You need to explain what ME21N is and how it is calculated if you want the same calculation to be performed in Excel. It seems t me that this question is more about SAP than about Excel. -- Also, please don't post answers to your own question if you don't have an answer. This is not a chat forum. You may want to take the [tour] and learn [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in SAP it only round up the first time when you run the script. Just add a custom code in your process to input the quantity the second time. It will be overwritten the first time, but never the second time.

Comment: Mark it as answer